# Qt передача данных в потоки

Tags: qt, многопоточность

Здравствуйте, возможно ли передать указатель на массив данных в два и более потоков только для чтения, данные не изменяются, будут ли потоки иметь одновременный доступ к данным?

Comment: да, одновременно один и тот же массив могут читать несколько потоков.

Answer (score 1):

Да, чтение из массива можно производить параллельно из нескольких потоков. Если потоки будут пытаться записывать что-то в массив, то можно передать константный указатель:

```
    int mas[5] = {1, 2, 3, 8};
    const int *ptr = mas;
    qDebug() << ptr[3]; // ok
    ptr[4] = 2; // error
```

Comment: А как передать в поток, например qvector<int> *arr? Через сигналы можно или при создании потока?

Comment: @Игорь добавьте код, которым вы создаёте поток